# Pagination with searching is not working

Tags: php, mysql, search, pagination

I am facing problem of pagination with searching not working.I am trying to paginate data with searching but there are no data paginate on second and third page.please help me.here is my code.

```
function paginationData($str,$num,$start,$sql,$perpage){
  $pagination = new Pagination; 
  $config['base_url'] = $str;
  $config['total_rows'] = $num;
  $config['per_page'] = $perpage;
  $config['cur_page'] = $start;
  $config['prefix'] = '&p=';
  $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
  $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
  $pagination->initialize($config); 
  $sql .= " LIMIT ".$start." , ".$config['per_page'];
  $res = qry($sql,2);   
  $data['listArr'] = $res;  
  $data['Total'] = $num;    
  $data['links'] =  $pagination->create_links();
  $data['per_page'] = $config['per_page']; 
  return $data;
}

$where = '';
$order_by = " ORDER BY parent_id,id_category ASC";  
$search = '';
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];
$search_term = $_REQUEST['word_search'];
if(@$search_term)
    $where = " where name like '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql = "select id_category,name,parent_id from category".$where.$order_by;      
$total_rec = qry($sql,3);
$page = $base_url.'categories.php?word_search='.$search_term;
$start = $_GET['p']?$_GET['p']:0;
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r ($total_rec);
//die();
$perpage=10;
$data = paginationData($page,$total_rec,$start,$sql,$perpage);
```

Comment: Your function name is spelled incorrectly. "pagiationData" should be "paginationData"

Comment: I dare you to set you ini settings to `E_STRICT | E_ALL` and display errors... you'll have to scroll a long way down before you can see the actual output of your script